# Calling SQL Package Procedure From Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have an oracle SQL procedure that I would like to call from my Java code but I can't quite figure out how to do that. I know my procedure works fine, since when I use them in SQLDeveloper I have no issues. When I call from my Java code I get a SQLSyntaxErrorException: invalid SQL statement.

Here is the code I have so far...

```
private DataSource datasource;

private static final Map<String, String> SQL_KEYS = new HashMap<String, String>();

static {
    SQL_KEYS.put("updatePassword", 
            "EXEC MY_VIEW_SECURITY.CHANGE_PASSWORD(?, ?, ?)");
}

public void updatePassword(String username, String old_password, String new_password) throws SQLException {
    Connection con = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;

    try {
        con = datasource.getConnection();
        cstmt = con.prepareCall(SQL_KEYS.get("updatePassword"));

        cstmt.setString(1, username);
        cstmt.setString(2, old_password);
        cstmt.setString(3, new_password);

        cstmt.executeUpdate();      

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        con.close();
        cstmt.close();
    }
}
```

Is the updatePassword string that I have not correct syntax for the Java code, because it works correctly in SQLDeveloper?

I have tried switching the EXEC to CALL in the statement which gave me SQLSyntaxErrorException: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session. I'm not sure if that is a move in the right direction or not.

Comment: Are you using an IDE?...you can set a breakpoint and check the value of `SQL_KEYS.get("updatePassword")`...a I'm also sure that you need to just run `execute` instead of `executeUpdate`

Comment: @Hackerman I am but SQL_KEYS.get("updatePassword") is just "EXEC MY_VIEW_SECURITY.CHANGE_PASSWORD(?, ?, ?)" as I defined it. It never changes. Unless you're talking about the CallableStatement as I set the strings in it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I mentioned that it was oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXEC` is not a [SQL command](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) so you can't use it from JDBC.

To [run a stored procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#calling_javadb_mysql) you need to use `{call ...}` when preparing the `CallableStatement`:

```
cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call Y_VIEW_SECURITY.CHANGE_PASSWORD(?, ?, ?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, username);
cstmt.setString(2, old_password);
cstmt.setString(3, new_password);
```

Note the `{` and `}` that are part of the String passed to `prepareCall()`

Comment: Ah, okay thank you. I was getting an error when I tried CALL so I wasn't sure which direction to move. Now I know what to focus on.